# Creating Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: r

I am trying to get a stacked bar chart with my codes in R, but I end up getting a bar chart, instead. I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong with my codes. I need help. Below is the code:

```
car_exp = data.frame(type = c("Exp1", "Exp1", "Exp2", "Exp2", "Exp1"),
                     date = c("Sep 10", "Sep 11", "Sep 12", "Sep 13", "Sep 14"),
                     speed = c(60, 65, 50, 70, 55))
result = ggplot(data = car_exp, mapping = aes(x = date, y = speed, fill = type))
result + geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Each date has only one observation, so there is no value to stack

Comment: `date` column is completely unique, `ggplot` can't find where it should stack the bars.